# Naive processing code is too slow -- suspect that there are better structures to us

Tags: processing

[image]

To learn `processing.py` I implemented a few software-defined [pintographs](http://www.waynesthisandthat.com/pintographs.html).

I didn't write the [first version in an 'orthodox' style](https://github.com/soilstack/pintograph/blob/master/scissor_pinto/scissor_pinto.pyde).  Instead I use `noloop()` in the setup and draw all the dots of under a single for-loop in the `draw()` function.  Then I'm finished.  This is the faster version (2s still seems long for something this simple)

The [next version uses what I think is more correct way to do things in Processing](https://github.com/soilstack/pintograph/blob/master/scissor_pinto_correct_flow/scissor_pinto_correct_flow.pyde).  I don't use `noloop()` and instead of a for-loop,  I just use the endless `draw()` calls to increment through and draw the dots.  I don't refresh with `background()` between draw() calls.  I just incrementally add new dots.  This is too slow.

I could say, "well don't use the orthdox style then...."  But that won't work, as I want to a[nimate the linkage arms as they draw out the pattern](https://github.com/soilstack/pintograph/blob/master/scissor_pinto_correct_flow_animated_arms/scissor_pinto_correct_flow_animated_arms.pyde).  For that I need `background()` on each `draw()` cycle, then to redraw all the dots and draw the last location of the linkage arm.

If you look at the three examples, the initial conditions and number of cycles is same for all.  The first example runs say in 2 seconds. The second in 20.  The third, even longer, and it acted increasingly unstable I think.

I'm suspicious that there are more advanced methods I should be using to do this.  It seem impossibly slow for such a relatively simple thing.   Or perhaps I am not implementing the simple solutions correctly. Wondering how fluent `processing.py` programmers would implment somethign like this.